# ERROR: PWM Generation using pigpio C library

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pwm, pigpio, pi-gpio

I am working on the RPI-CM4 board with raspbian buster OS.

I am trying to generate the 38KHz PWM wave using [pigpio](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio) the library. My code is as follows.

```
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PWM_PIN 18

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   gpioCfgClock(1, 0, 1);

   if (gpioInitialise()<0) return 1;

   gpioSetPWMfrequency(PWM_PIN, 38000);

   gpioPWM(PWM_PIN, 128);

   while (1) { sleep(1); }

   gpioTerminate();
}
```

At the output, I am getting the PWM wave generated @27.63 KHz.
[image: pwm_wave]

Will you please help me to know,
How do I set up a PWM clock to get a 38KHz resolution?

Answer (score 1):

pigpio supports two types of PWM.

1. DMA timed PwM on GPIO 0-31.  This has a limited number of frequencies and duty cycle resolution.  See [gpioSetPWMfrequency](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetPWMfrequency) for the permitted frequencies.

I am not sure why you seem to be getting 27 kHz, I'd expect 40 kHz from the way it is being setup.

2. Hardware timed PWM on GPIO 12-13, 18-19.  This is fully hardware PWM.  See [gpioHardwarePWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioHardwarePWM).

As an aside I would use waves to generate IR carrier.  There is a Python [example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py).

Comment: Using the [gpioHardwarePWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioHardwarePWM) I am able to generate the PWM waves > 50KHz after that the wave gets displeased 50% duty cycle. I want to drop down it up to 30KHz. will you please help me to know, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Spent some time on this & found that the gpioHardwarePWM will work only on PWM channel-1 (gpio 19-13). ( [referance link](https://www.codecubix.eu/linux/hardware-pwm-with-raspberry-pi-zero/) ) I am able to get the 38KHz wave on channel1 (gpio 19), but in between some pulses are missed. Now, will you please help me to know, 1. how do I configure channels to the hardware PWM? 2. Why the pulses are get missed in-between?

Comment: I have solved this problem by using [gpioWaveAddGeneric](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioWaveAddGeneric)